Sequencing of a group with certain second element
A non-trivial finite group $G$ of order $n$ is said to be sequenceable if its elements can be arranged in a sequence $(b_1, b_2,...,b_n)$ in such a way that the partial products $(a_1, a_2,...,a_n)$,
where $a_i = b_1b_2 \dots b_i$, are distinct. The sequence $(b_1, b_2,...,b_n)$ is called a sequencing for $G$.  It is obvious, that $a_1=b_1=e$.
It is known, that $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ is sequenceable. Moreover, in paper "Directed paths of diagonals within polygons" (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220189804_Directed_paths_of_diagonals_within_polygons) it is proved that every element $ x \in \overline{0,2^{n-1}-1}$ can be the second element of sequencing of $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ (where we enumerate elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ by usual way) by inductive building of such sequencing. But they proved the statement using pictures, which are difficult to understand. For example, I can't restore sequencing, which are used as induction base ($x=3$ and $x=11$). (by restoring I mean getting sequencing from the picture in the paper)
So, I want my second element of sequencing of $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ to be $2^{n-2}$. Does anyone has any idea how to do this or maybe explain how to interpret the pictures in the paper?  Any help would be appreciated.

Please define all non-standard notation before first use.  I don't know what the notation $\overline{0,2^n-1}$ is supposed to represent.  I don't know what is meant by "restore sequencing, which are used as induction base".  Please [edit] your post to clarify.
